# Hungary character encoding

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsstring

I'm trying to convert hungarian characters to NSData. 
Using the code page of PC865.

Here's here code.

```
NSString *test = @"őű";
NSStringEncoding *coding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingDOSNordic);
        NSData *myData = [test dataUsingEncoding:coding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSLog(@"my data %@", myData);
```

The output that I receive is my data <3f3f>

They both are different character, but why do I receive the same data and actually they both are wrong data after looking at the PC865 table.

Comment: search for UTF-8 encoding, with that will work, otherwise not, because those 2 letters will take 2 bytes at encoding , not 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code, `NSStringEncoding` is scalar type, not a pointer to an Objective-C object. Therefore it must be

```
NSStringEncoding coding = ...
```

without the `*`.

But the main problem is that the Code Page 865 (Nordic Languages, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_865)
does not contain the characters

```
ő = U+0151 = LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
ű = U+0171 = LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
```

Since you specified `allowLossyConversion:YES`, the conversion does not fail, but
replaces the characters with a question mark (0x3F).

If you choose the Code Page 852 instead (Central European languages, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852):

```
NSStringEncoding coding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingDOSLatin2);
```

then you will get the result `<8bfb>`.

Comment: Martin, thank you for your answer. 
However I'm print these character to the printer and the printer only read PC865 code page, hence I need that 2 character to be 94 and 81 respectively. Possible to get that?

Comment: @user774150: Character 94 in PC865 is "ö", not "ő". And character 81 is "ü", not "ű".